# Publishing DotNetNuke using WebMatrix

Tags: dotnetnuke, publishing, webmatrix

I have just attempted to publish a site via WebMatrix and have hit a problem.

When I try to run the site I get an error;

```
Domain Name www.MyClientsDomain.com.au Does Not Exist In The Database
```

I have no idea what this is asking me.  I changed the `HTTPAlias` field in the `PortalAlias` table like it said at the bottom of the error page but that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be referring to the portal alias, you may just need to restart the site to see your changes.

Comment: +` Yup.  Noticed that one.  Problem was that the Hoster I am using, they say restart application but it doesn't really.  So I simply put a space in the web.config file and uploaded that again to force the restart.  :)  Thanks for the answer though.